# Why does erase from std::list give me a segfault?

Tags: c++, list, segmentation-fault

I've been working on some code in a function parsing system. It does this in a tree structure. At the moment, it keeps track of just the children, but I want to add information from the parents as well. Specifically, I'm trying to add a list of pointers that point to the parents. When I go delete the parents, though, I need to remove the pointers from the children. When I try to do this, I get a segfault.

Here is the constructor that sets up the list of _subnodes.

```
EBUnaryTermNode(EBTermNode * subnode) : _subnode(subnode){
      _subnode->_parents.push_back(this);
    };
```

Here is the destructor that calls the function that erases the the pointer to the parent.

```
virtual ~EBUnaryTermNode() {
      _subnode->eraseParent(this);
      if(_subnode->_parents.size() == 0 && _subnode->_holders.size() == 0)
        delete _subnode;
    };
```

Here is the function that erases the pointer to the parent.

```
void eraseParent(EBTermNode * victim)
{
    std::list<EBTermNode *>::iterator it;
    for(it = _parents.begin(); it != _parents.end(); ++it)
         if(*it == victim)
         {
             std::cout << victim << std::endl;
             _parents.erase(it);
             break;
         }
}
```

The class EBUnaryTermNode inherits from a base class EBTermNode, which is defined here.

```
class EBTermNode
  {
  public:
    virtual ~EBTermNode(){};
    virtual EBTermNode * clone() const = 0;

    virtual std::string stringify() const = 0;
    virtual unsigned int substitute(const EBSubstitutionRuleList & /*rule*/) { return 0; }
    virtual int precedence() const = 0;
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const EBTermNode & node)
    {
      return os << node.stringify();
    }
    void eraseParent(EBTermNode * victim)
    {
      std::list<EBTermNode *>::iterator it;
      for(it = _parents.begin(); it != _parents.end(); ++it)
        if(*it == victim)
        {
          std::cout << victim << std::endl;
          std::cout << *it << std::endl;
          _parents.erase(it);
          break;
        }
    }

    std::list<EBTermNode *> _parents;
    std::list<EBTerm *> _holders;
  };
```

It seems to work for awhile (about 25 times from the cout statements) before it runs into a segfault.

When I look through the stack from the debugger, I get this:

```
Thread 1 "phase_field-dbg" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffe9adbf8d in __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator_base::_M_singular (this=0x421010)
    at ../../../../../gcc-8.3.0/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/debug.cc:403
403     ../../../../../gcc-8.3.0/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/debug.cc: No such file or directory.
(gdb) up
#1  0x00007ffff77c14a2 in __gnu_debug::_Safe_sequence<std::__debug::list<ExpressionBuilder::EBTermNode*, std::allocator<ExpressionBuilder::EBTermNode*> > >::_M_invalidate_if<__gnu_debug::_Equal_to<std::__cxx1998::_List_const_iterator<ExpressionBuilder::EBTermNode*> > > 
    (this=0xa4e598, __pred=...)
    at /opt/moose/gcc-8.3.0/include/c++/8.3.0/debug/safe_sequence.tcc:48
48                  if (!__victim->_M_singular() && __pred(__victim->base()))
(gdb) 
#2  0x00007ffff77bda03 in std::__debug::list<ExpressionBuilder::EBTermNode*, std::allocator<ExpressionBuilder::EBTermNode*> >::_M_erase (this=0xa4e598, __position=...)             
    at /opt/moose/gcc-8.3.0/include/c++/8.3.0/debug/list:490
490             this->_M_invalidate_if(_Equal(__position));
(gdb) 
#3  0x00007ffff77b918c in std::__debug::list<ExpressionBuilder::EBTermNode*, std::allocator<ExpressionBuilder::EBTermNode*> >::erase (this=0xa4e598, __position=...)                
    at /opt/moose/gcc-8.3.0/include/c++/8.3.0/debug/list:503
503             return iterator(_M_erase(__position.base()), this);
(gdb) 
#4  0x00007ffff77b231c in ExpressionBuilder::EBTermNode::eraseParent (this=0xa4e590, 
    victim=0xa4e7a0)
    at /home/jason/Research/GBResearch/projects/moose/modules/phase_field/build/header_symlinks/ExpressionBuilder.h:95                                                              
95                _parents.erase(it);
(gdb) 
#5  0x00007ffff77b27ab in ExpressionBuilder::EBUnaryTermNode::~EBUnaryTermNode (
    this=0xa4e7a0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /home/jason/Research/GBResearch/projects/moose/modules/phase_field/build/header_symlinks/ExpressionBuilder.h:155                                                             
155           _subnode->eraseParent(this);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some more context - the function you posted seems fine. Please have a look on [documentation on how to create MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @zett42 the loop `break`s after the one element was erased, so thats not the problem

Comment: Can you tell what `_parents` ?

Comment: I added some more info. Is that enough? There's not much else that goes on in the class besides a stringify function that returns the equation as a string.

Comment: it is enough when you can reproduce the error with only the code you posted here, if not also someone else cannot reproduce it

Comment: Why does a node have multiple parents? In any case, the segfault likely suggests that the subnode is being freed before one of its still-active parents is freed, thus `eraseParent()` gets called on an invalid subnode. The subnode's destructor needs to loop through its active parents setting their `_subnode` pointer to null, and then the parents need to check for that null whenever they want to access their `_subnode`. This would be easier to manage if you use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: OK, I've added some more. I believe this should be enough to reproduce the issue. Also, there are multiple parents because I'm doing some matrix algebra which uses the same nodes over and over. Instead of doing a deep copy, I opted to just pass the pointer to the existing node. I've been fairly careful about my memory allocation, so it should only delete the subnode after all parents are deleted. I'll check that again, though.

Comment: @JasonMeziere "*Instead of doing a deep copy, I opted to just pass the pointer to the existing node*" - That is a good argument *in favor* of using `std::shared_ptr` to share objects. You are manually doing what `std::shared_ptr` is already designed to do for you, and it is a standard C++ class.

Comment: Unless I got it wrong, I think I accounted for the parents setting the _subnode to null. In order for a destructor to be called on the _subnode, all of the parents have to already have been destroyed. I will look into shared_ptr, though. Thank you for that.

Comment: @JasonMeziere you haven't shown any of the code related to `_holders`, which also affects a node's lifetime

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry I never got back to you. I switched over to your idea of using std::shared_ptr and it worked beautifully. Much less to worry about. Thank you.